# How to create a delayed queue in RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, delay, pika

What is the easiest way to create a delay (or parking) queue with Python, Pika and RabbitMQ? I have seen an similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq), but none for Python.

I find this an useful idea when designing applications, as it allows us to throttle messages that needs to be re-queued again.

There are always the possibility that you will receive more messages than you can handle, maybe the HTTP server is slow, or the database is under too much stress.

I also found it very useful when something went wrong in scenarios where there is a zero tolerance to losing messages, and while re-queuing messages that could not be handled may solve that. It can also cause problems where the message will be queued over and over again. Potentially causing performance issues, and log spam.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I found this extremely useful when developing my applications. As it gives you an alternative to simply re-queuing your messages. This can easily reduce the complexity of your code, and is one of many powerful hidden features in RabbitMQ.

**Steps**

First we need to set up two basic channels, one for the main queue, and one for the delay queue. In my example at the end, I include a couple of additional flags that are not required, but makes the code more reliable; such as `confirm delivery`, `delivery_mode` and `durable`. You can find more information on these in the RabbitMQ [manual](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

After we have set up the channels we add a binding to the main channel that we can use to send messages from the delay channel to our main queue.

```
channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct',
                   queue='hello')
```

Next we need to configure our delay channel to forward messages to the main queue once they have expired.

```
delay_channel.queue_declare(queue='hello_delay', durable=True,  arguments={
  'x-message-ttl' : 5000,
  'x-dead-letter-exchange' : 'amq.direct',
  'x-dead-letter-routing-key' : 'hello'
})
```

- [x-message-ttl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) *(Message - Time To Live)*

  This is normally used to automatically remove old messages in the
  queue after a specific duration, but by adding two optional arguments we
  can change this behaviour, and instead have this parameter determine
  in milliseconds how long messages will stay in the delay queue.
- [x-dead-letter-routing-key](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)

  This variable allows us to transfer the message to a different queue
  once they have expired, instead of the default behaviour of removing
  it completely.
- [x-dead-letter-exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)

  This variable determines which Exchange used to transfer the message from hello_delay to hello queue.

**Publishing to the delay queue**

When we are done setting up all the basic Pika parameters you simply send a message to the delay queue using basic publish.

```
delay_channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello_delay',
                      body="test",
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
```

Once you have executed the script you should see the following queues created in your RabbitMQ management module. 
[image]

**Example.**

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
               'localhost'))

# Create normal 'Hello World' type channel.
channel = connection.channel()
channel.confirm_delivery()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', durable=True)

# We need to bind this channel to an exchange, that will be used to transfer 
# messages from our delay queue.
channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct',
                   queue='hello')

# Create our delay channel.
delay_channel = connection.channel()
delay_channel.confirm_delivery()

# This is where we declare the delay, and routing for our delay channel.
delay_channel.queue_declare(queue='hello_delay', durable=True,  arguments={
  'x-message-ttl' : 5000, # Delay until the message is transferred in milliseconds.
  'x-dead-letter-exchange' : 'amq.direct', # Exchange used to transfer the message from A to B.
  'x-dead-letter-routing-key' : 'hello' # Name of the queue we want the message transferred to.
})

delay_channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello_delay',
                      body="test",
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))

print " [x] Sent"
```

Comment: what happens when each message to be published has varying ttl? how do I do that?

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference. Simply move the ```TTL``` to the Message properties instead. Feel free to open a new question and link it here and I'll answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you've answered it already but after some reading I found that its not reliable since a dead message can be stuck behind healthy ones and so even though they expire they still cant move on.

Comment: You could probably combine it with a high queue TTL, and then set the per message TTL to a lower value, but like you mentioned it might not work as intended. I have never tried this with a per message TTL.

Comment: I was looking a similar solution for hours. Thanks for that! Works perfect. "X-" arguments should be better documented.

Comment: @Marconi , could you please link to the articles that you read to come to that conclusion or further explain the downside?

Comment: @ManuelZubieta sorry its been some time now so I don't remember exactly where I read it.

Comment: @ManuelZubieta The caveats sub-section of the Per-Message TTL section in the RabbitMQ TTL docs linked to above (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) explains how expired messages are only expired from the head of the queue. That appears to kill this answer as a viable solution for per message TTL.

Comment: @Caolite: is there an issue in creating a queue for each set of delayed messages?

Comment: @eandersson I like this solution, but what if the topology is so that there are dozens of main queues, and dozens of delay queues?

Answer (score 17):

You can use RabbitMQ official plugin: **x-delayed-message** .

Firstly, download and copy the [ez file](http://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins/v3.5.x/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-0.0.1-rmq3.5.x-9bf265e4.ez) into *Your_rabbitmq_root_path/plugins*

Secondly, enable the plugin (do not need to restart the server):

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Finally, publish your message with "x-delay" headers like:

```
headers.put("x-delay", 5000);
```

**Notice:**

It does not ensure your message's safety, cause if your message expires just during your rabbitmq-server's downtime, unfortunately the message is lost. So **be careful** when you use this scheme.

Enjoy it and more info in [rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange)

Answer (score 8):

FYI, how to do this in Spring 3.2.x.

```
<rabbit:queue name="delayQueue" durable="true" queue-arguments="delayQueueArguments"/>

<rabbit:queue-arguments id="delayQueueArguments">
  <entry key="x-message-ttl">
    <value type="java.lang.Long">10000</value>
  </entry>
  <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="finalDestinationTopic"/>
  <entry key="x-dead-letter-routing-key" value="finalDestinationQueue"/>
</rabbit:queue-arguments>


<rabbit:fanout-exchange name="finalDestinationTopic">
  <rabbit:bindings>
    <rabbit:binding queue="finalDestinationQueue"/>
  </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>
```

Answer (score 4):

NodeJS implementation.

Everything is pretty clear from the code.
Hope it will save somebody's time.

```
var ch = channel;
ch.assertExchange("my_intermediate_exchange", 'fanout', {durable: false});
ch.assertExchange("my_final_delayed_exchange", 'fanout', {durable: false});

// setup intermediate queue which will never be listened.
// all messages are TTLed so when they are "dead", they come to another exchange
ch.assertQueue("my_intermediate_queue", {
      deadLetterExchange: "my_final_delayed_exchange",
      messageTtl: 5000, // 5sec
}, function (err, q) {
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, "my_intermediate_exchange", '');
});

ch.assertQueue("my_final_delayed_queue", {}, function (err, q) {
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, "my_final_delayed_exchange", '');

      ch.consume(q.queue, function (msg) {
          console.log("delayed - [x] %s", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Message in Rabbit queue can be delayed in 2 ways 
     - using QUEUE TTL 
     - using Message TTL
If all messages in queue are to be delayed for fixed time use queue TTL.
If each message has to be delayed by varied time use Message TTL.
I have explained it using python3 and pika module.
pika BasicProperties argument 'expiration' in milliseconds has to be set to delay message in delay queue.
After setting expiration time, publish message to a delayed_queue ("not actual queue where consumers are waiting to consume") , once message in delayed_queue expires, message will be routed to a actual queue using exchange 'amq.direct'

```
def delay_publish(self, messages, queue, headers=None, expiration=0):
    """
    Connect to RabbitMQ and publish messages to the queue
    Args:
        queue (string): queue name
        messages (list or single item): messages to publish to rabbit queue
        expiration(int): TTL in milliseconds for message
    """
    delay_queue = "".join([queue, "_delay"])
    logging.info('Publishing To Queue: {queue}'.format(queue=delay_queue))
    logging.info('Connecting to RabbitMQ: {host}'.format(
        host=self.rabbit_host))
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(
       RABBIT_MQ_USER, RABBIT_MQ_PASS)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
       rabbit_host, RABBIT_MQ_PORT,
        RABBIT_MQ_VHOST, credentials, heartbeat_interval=0)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue, durable=True)

    channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct',
                       queue=queue)
    delay_channel = connection.channel()
    delay_channel.queue_declare(queue=delay_queue, durable=True,
                                arguments={
                                    'x-dead-letter-exchange': 'amq.direct',
                                    'x-dead-letter-routing-key': queue
                                })

    properties = pika.BasicProperties(
        delivery_mode=2, headers=headers, expiration=str(expiration))

    if type(messages) not in (list, tuple):
        messages = [messages]

    try:
        for message in messages:
            try:
                json_data = json.dumps(message)
            except Exception as err:
                logging.error(
                    'Error Jsonify Payload: {err}, {payload}'.format(
                        err=err, payload=repr(message)), exc_info=True
                )
                if (type(message) is dict) and ('data' in message):
                    message['data'] = {}
                    message['error'] = 'Payload Invalid For JSON'
                    json_data = json.dumps(message)
                else:
                    raise

            try:
                delay_channel.basic_publish(
                    exchange='', routing_key=delay_queue,
                    body=json_data, properties=properties)
            except Exception as err:
                logging.error(
                    'Error Publishing Data: {err}, {payload}'.format(
                        err=err, payload=json_data), exc_info=True
                )
                raise

    except Exception:
        raise

    finally:
        logging.info(
            'Done Publishing. Closing Connection to {queue}'.format(
                queue=delay_queue
            )
        )
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your scenario and needs, I would recommend the following approaches,

- Using the official plugin, https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/, but it will have a capacity issue if the total count of delayed messages exceeds certain number (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues/72), it will not have the high availability option and it will suffer lose of data when it runs out of delayed time during a MQ restart.
- Implement a set of cascading delayed queues just like NServiceBus did (https://docs.particular.net/transports/rabbitmq/delayed-delivery).