# How to poll an AMQP queue using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have the use case that I need to wait 2 hours before consuming messages from an AMQP (we use Rabbit) queue.

EDIT:  To clarify my use case... I need each individual message to wait 2 hours before being read.  E.g.  Message 1 arrives at 10am and Message 2 arrives at 10:15.  I need Message 1 to be read at 12p and Message 2 to be read at 12:15p.

We are using Spring Integration 3.x.

The `int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter` is message driven and doesn't have a polling option from what I can find.

A couple things I've thought of:

- Set `auto-startup` to false and manually start the inbound channel adapter using a quartz job.
- Create my own custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` that is based on polling (not sure how easy this would be)
- Configure a "delay queue" in rabbitmq using this method: [How to create a delayed queue in RabbitMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014584/how-to-create-a-delayed-queue-in-rabbitmq)
- EDIT: add 4th option:  Use `delayer` to delay each message for 2 hours: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, how I solved the issue.  (Used solution #3).

```
<rabbit:queue name="delayQueue" durable="true">
  <rabbit:queue-arguments>
    <entry key="x-message-ttl">
       <value type="java.lang.Long">7200000</
     </entry>
     <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="finalDestinationTopic"/>
     <entry key="x-dead-letter-routing-key" value="finalDestinationQueue"/>
  </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="finalDestinationTopic">
  <rabbit:bindings>
    <rabbit:binding queue="finalDestinationQueue" pattern="finalDestinationQueue"/>
  </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have a polling inbound adapter. #1 is easy. For #2, the simplest would be to use a `RabbitTemplate` and invoke `receive()` from an `inbound-channel-adapter` in a POJO.

I would go with #1; you don't need quartz, you can use a simple Spring scheduled task and a control bus to start the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  After rethinking over the weekend, I'm not sure either solution would solve my problem though.  I didn't state my use case very well.  I need to have each individual message wait 2 hours.  I'm thinking options 3 or newly added option 4 in my question may be the best solution.

Comment: For that use case (every message delayed 2 hours) then option #3 is the way to go; I would not introduce a delayer.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is about to use `PollableAmqpChannel`:

```
<int-amqp:channel id="myQueueName" message-driven="false"/>
```

and provide the `<poller>` for the subscriber to that channel.

There is no reason to send messages to that channel (because you will poll messages from Rabbit Queue) and, right, it looks like `anti-pattern`, but it is a hook how to avoid any workarounds with direct `RabbitTemplate` usage via SpEL.

**UPDATE**

`<delayer>` can help you, but it depends of your requirements. If you don't want to poll messages from RabbitMQ, you should use the workaround above. But if you just don't want to **process** message until some time is elapsed, you can just 'delay' it for that time.

Don't forget to add persistent `message-store` to avoid losing messages during that period and unexpected application failure.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good workaround.  The one problem now...I'm not sure that a pollable channel would work for me because if I poll every 2 hours for only 1 message, the queue could get really backed up.  Updated my question to clarify my use case.

Comment: Added comments on the matter